# jQuery - inserted anchor tags do not wrap correctly

Tags: jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I have the following snippet of jQuery:

```
$(elementId).prevAll().appendTo(prevDiv);
```

It works but the problem is that all the elements selected by the prevAll() function are appended to the prevDiv div without spaces between them. This means that the content of this div (a collection of anchor tags) does not wrap onto multiple lines.

How would I add spaces after each collection item or force wrap for each element?

EDIT: As requested, here's some HTML that demonstrates the problem:

```
<div style="width:200px; overflow:hidden; border:2px"><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-1">1</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-2">2</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-3">3</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-4">4</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-5">5</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-6">6</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-7">7</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-8">8</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-9">9</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-10">10</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-11">11</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-12">12</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-13">13</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-14">14</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-15">15</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-16">16</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-17">17</a><a style="padding:5px;"  href="http://www.domain.com/" id="p-18">18</a></div>
```

Comment: Give us an example of the HTML that gives the error. You can use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change them all to be block level elements.

```
$(elementId).prevAll().css( { display: 'block' } ).appendTo(prevDiv);
```

or if you really need to append some text.

```
$(elementId).prevAll()
            .appendTo(prevDiv)
            .after( " " );
```

Comment: @tvanson I think block should be in quotes i.e. { display: 'block' }

Comment: +1 great solution. using `.css('display', 'block')` might be also good, if someone does not prefer to use the object notation with a simple rule.

Comment: @cybernate - absolutely correct, been editing too many CSS files recently.

Comment: I haven't had any success with that display block directive. Yes, it splits each element onto a separate line but I wanted the elements to next to each other and wrap in the div.

Answer (score 2):

@tvanfosson's solution is great, but if you want to separate behaviour and presentation, add it to your CSS:

```
#div_you_are_inserting_to a { display: block; }
```

This is a choice of preference, personally I don't really like adding CSS rules to my jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elementId).prevAll().addClass('myDisplayBlockClass').appendTo(prevDiv);
```